# How do I run a segment of code every frame with Scene Kit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Scene kit doesn't have an update function, so how would I implement a simple if statement every frame.  For instance, to see if an object is at rest before the frame is rendered?  I'm programming in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a delegate to your SCNView and implement renderer:updateAtTime: (see SCNSceneRenderer.h > SCNSceneRendererDelegate )

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I'm adding the SCNSceneRenderDelegate to the GameViewController class and adding this: optional func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
        println("update")
    }  xcode complains about the underscore before aRenderer.  Then it complains about using optional, saying It only works with protocol members.  using just func works, but runs once and crashes the app.